# Zeros of modular forms in higher dimensional cases

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I have seen some results about the distribution and in particular number of zeros (in a fundamental domain) of a modular form on the upper half plane. Are there similar results about
modular forms considered as holomrphic functions on Siegel upper half space?

Comment: In the higher-dimensional case the vanishing is going to be along subvarieties of positive dimension, not isolated point, so questions about "number" will need to be phrased very carefully.

Comment: Where did you read about these results?